# Unable to set MatTable datasource

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-table

I am in a bit of a pickle. I have component which have MatTable which I am using to show data. I have a new requirement which requires to trigger a http call based on some short cut defined and update the data source.

I am using ngrx for state-management and my data is stored in a store. Before adding the shortcuts I fetched the data once and apply pagination and it was working fine before. Now, when I trigger a http call to fetch the data grid shows very weird behavior sometimes it doesn't show the data however data is there and my paginator is updated accordingly.

Here is my code :

```
 this.store.select(selectSearchData).subscribe(data => {
  this.paginator && this.paginator.firstPage();
  this.selectedElement = null;
  this.dataSource.data = data; // Data is there in the 'data' variable but it doesn't update the datasource
  this.activePageDataChunk = this.dataSource.filteredData.slice(
    0,
    this.pageSize
  );
  this.paginator && (this.paginator.pageSize = this.pageSize);
  this.count = -1;

});
```

I have the following code in my ngOnInit method :

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.connect().subscribe(data => {
      this.activePageDataChunk = data;
      this.activePageDataChunk =  this.searchService.searchResultmapper(this.activePageDataChunk,this.language);
      this.store.dispatch(UPDATE_PAGINATIION_DIRECTORY({directories:this.activePageDataChunk}));
    });
  }
```

I have logged the data and it is there but somehow my datasource is not updating. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo?

Answer (score 1):

Try to load data into `MatTable` using this way

```
dataSource : MatTableDataSource<any>; //replace any with your type if you know
```

After you get reponse from Api

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
//replace data as per your response
```

Comment: I did that and it loads the data in the grid but then my paginator start working abnormally. Showing only 219 records instead of showing no of records present in the service response.

Comment: But, you've tried to set your paginator (this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;) after filling the MatTableDataSource?